# SL(2,n) transitivity

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

$SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is mobius transformation and is 3-transitive over $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty$ . What is the analog over which $SL(2,n)$ is 3-transitive (if any)?

I actually want this for PSL, but it would be sufficient I guess.

Thanks

Comment: When you write $SL(2,n)$ do you really mean $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Now, I mean over a finite field $F_n$

Comment: have you tried the projective space $\mathbb{P}^1 F_q$ of $F_q$?

Comment: Yes, it worked.